# Need to run remote script on remote machine from local machine Unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh, remote-server

I want to run a script test.sh which is located on machine A on A itself but from machine B. Is there any way to do the same in Unix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ssh` to achieve this:

```
ssh -t user@host '/path/to/test.sh'
```

According to `man ssh`, this is what the `-t` option does:

> Force pseudo-tty allocation.  This can be used to execute arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be useful,
>   e.g. when implementing menu services.  Multiple -t force tty
>   allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.

Comment: what is -t for? I tried the following command ssh user@host '/path/to/script' but it taking local path and finding local script.